# Why don't nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 16.04 work properly?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) and have nvidia graphics model:

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)
```

I've tried switching from the default Nouveau display driver to several Nvidia binary drivers using (for e.g.):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```

However, after restarting my machine, the graphics are clunky and it's difficult to use multiple monitors (sometimes, the other monitors are not detected at all). I've also tried nvidia-352 and nvidia-370.

Does anybody know why switching to any of the nvidia drivers doesn't work well? Am I not using the correct nvidia drivers?

Comment: 367 is the only version recommended by Nvidia for your card.

Comment: Don't feel bad when I tried `367` (from the `Additional Drivers` section) on my GT650M and rebooted I got a black screen with frozen cursor. I didn't use the PPA like you did though. I'll keenly follow your question to see what answers come up. I don't really need the laptop's Nvidia as the Intel HD4000 graphics work superbly for me. I was just curious after reading all the bug reports.

Comment: Like a bunch of others these days, I'd like to use a gpu with TensorFlow, Torch, Caffe, etc., and for this, I need to use an nvidia card with CUDA and cuDNN.